# É possível publicar no facebook através do meu sistema?

Tags: firebase, facebook, facebook-sdk, api

Olá, a dúvida é simples, quero fazer uma integração do meu sistema com o facebook.

Gostaria de saber os passos necessários para que eu consiga postar em meu sistema e automaticamente ele gere um post em uma page do facebook e também compartilhe essas postagens em um número X de perfis.

Não sei se é possível a parte compartilhamento com alguns perfis, mas já ouvi dizer que é possível fazer isso tudo com o firebase, porém até agora não consegui encontrar uma forma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Então. Para que você envie postagens para o Facebook, é necessário que o seu usuário ou página dê essas permissões.

A documentação para esse procedimento está aqui:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api

Mas devo lembrar que esse é um conjunto de permissões especiais e o Facebook não dará essas permissões a menos que você seja o dono da conta ou página.

Boa sorte no seu projeto.

Comment: Perfeito, e é possível enviar para  mais de uma conta? Ou então melhor ainda, compartilhar com meu usuário da postagem que foi feita por esta integração?